# Is C# method sealed or virtual by default?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I know the definitions of  `virtual` and `sealed` keywords, but if you don't use either of them with a method, can the method be overriden by default?

I am coming from vb.net background. It goes like this in vb.net (from MSDN):

> If the Overridable or NotOverridable modifier is not specified, the
>   default setting depends on whether the property or method overrides a
>   base class property or method. If the property or method overrides a
>   base class property or method, the default setting is Overridable;
>   otherwise, it is NotOverridable.

I just want to know if that's also true in C#.

Comment: The fastest way is simply to check yourself, it's not more than about 10 lines of code to check.

Comment: @Zipper disagree. Google is faster. And the fact that someone asked this question allows me to Google it fast

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it cannot. You need to explicitly mark a method as virtual to allow it to be overridden in derived classes.

What you can do however, is hide a method by using the new keyword. (MSDN Documentation)

The sealed keyword is used on both class definitions and methods. It disallows inheriting from a class or overriding of a method. By default, if you don't use this keyword, others will be  able to inherit from your class. ([MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: note `sealed` applies to methods as well as classes.  You can seal a virtual method to prevent subtypes of yourself from overriding it.

Comment: Just to add that `new` keyword is implicit for a method in a derived class which is present in base class either as virtual or non-virtual method. Explicitly mentioning the `new` keyword in the declaration of the method in the derived class helps the programmer to understand the intent that - `The method you are looking at is not interested in participating in inheritance call hierarchy.`

Answer (score 6):

By default methods in C# are *not* virtual.

Answer (score 2):

No. Unlike Java, in C# methods are not `virtual` by default. They neither are `sealed`, but you cannot override them, because they are normal methods.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot override a non-virtual method. The new keyword only hides the base class implementation and is not a good practice.

Discussion on this with Anders Hejlsberg [here](http://www.artima.com/intv/nonvirtualP.html)